# TensorFlow LSTM for 4-D Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

if I have an input with shape `[None, None, None, 10]`, I want to do something like the following,

```py
input = tf.placeholder([None, None, None, 10], dtype=tf.float32)
length = tf.placeholder([None, None], dtype=tf.int32)
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units=10)
def fn(inp): 
  output, _ = tf.dynamic_rnn(cell, inp[0], sequence_length=inp[1])
  return output

tf.map_fn(fn, (input, length), dtype=tf.float32)
```

But it does not work for the automatic gradient derivation, which produces error like the following,

```
Cannot use 'XXX' as input to 'gradients/YYY/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3_grad/TensorArrayReadV3/f_acc' 
because 'XXX' is in a while loop.
```

Is this a limitation of `TensorFlow` that it cannot handle the nested `while_loop` (`dynamic_rnn` and `map_fn` both run a `while_loop` behind the scene), or there is a way to work around this ?

Comment: I think you're trying to do the `map_fn` because you have a variable length sequence? Am I right? If so, the correct way to handle a variable length sequence is to pad the shorter sequence lengths with 0's and pass a truth matrix to `dynmaic_rnn` to tell it which values are padded and which are not. See this guide: https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html

Comment: @DavidParks The matrix is already padded with 0 ... I just give an oversimplified example to explain my problem. sequence_length for dynamic_rnn has to be of the shape [batch_size] according to the doc, however in my case the sequence length is [batch_size, ?], which has to be given to all the sub-tensors coming out of the original 4-D tensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow 1.6 has this issue fixed